# How to convert V1Ingress object to yaml file

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I'm trying to convert v1Ingress object to standard yaml file. However comparing the saved file with it's manifest file using `kubectl get ing example -o yaml` shows different files. Any pointers to solve this

```
from kubernetes import client, config
import kubernetes.client
from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
import yaml
 

config.load_kube_config("k8s.yml")
v1 = client.NetworkingV1Api()
api_client = client.ApiClient()

namespace = "sample"

try:
    api_response = v1.list_namespaced_ingress(namespace)
 
    for ing in api_response.items:
        name = ing.metadata.name
        with open("{}.yml".format(name), "w") as f:
            yaml.dump(api_client.sanitize_for_serialization(ing), f, default_flow_style=False)

except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling NetworkingV1Api->list_namespaced_ingress:", str(e), "\n")
```

Comment: 'kubectl get' usually adds multiple fields to the output (especially for Kube versions <1.19). Can you show the actual diff?

Comment: @VasiliAngapov For example, the v1Ingressobj has parameters like managed_fields when converted to yaml. However when I use `kubectl` with `-o yaml` flag, I don't see that

Comment: use --show-managed-fields flag to kubectl

Comment: @VasiliAngapov Actually I don't want those fields. I'm looking for ways in which kubernetes-python-client shall generate same manifest file as if I'm using `kubectl get ing example -o yaml`